# Can 'trains' be used as a synonym for 'postponement'

Tags: meaning, nouns, synonyms, collective-nouns

Was solving a cryptic crossword clue recently which reads

> Coaches for postponement (6)

The answer is 'trains' obvious from coaches , but dont get the postponement reference. The solution mentions

> Trains = postponement (collective noun)

Is this correct? Or is it even a synonym reference or something else?

Comment: Are you sure the question is related to trains?

Comment: I can never understand cryptic clues for crosswords. How is the answer obviously trains?

Comment: @Tucker _Coach_ can mean to teach someone something, to train them.  It can also mean a railroad car or a class of travel, coach, business, first. It's also the case that in the context of a crossword only one or two words will actually 'fit' into the crosswords wrt. which letters are shared with other words.

Comment: @Frank Ah! Coach! Train! Now I see it. Still, wow. Never would have crossed my mind. Guess my brain isn't wired to think that way.

Comment: Where is this crossword from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they might be having a little fun by suggesting that the collective noun for trains is *a postponement* as in

> A postponement of trains

I'm not sure if it is the proper collective noun for trains, but it's quite amusing. I found one reference in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aGlossary_of_collective_nouns_by_subject) where they say the collective noun for trains is `A postponement, cancellation of trains` and another here [A compendium of collective nouns, Woop Studios](http://books.google.co.th/books?id=aHhP_7zOG8wC&lpg=PA198&ots=X8Ga8ucsXc&dq=trains%20postponement%20collective%20noun&pg=PA198#v=onepage&q=trains%20postponement%20collective%20noun&f=false)

*Coaches for camels (6)* might have been better because the collective noun for *camels* is *train*.

> A train of camels

Comment: This seems plausible, though you'd never see something so loose in a 'standard' cryptic crossword (eg one in a British newspaper) unless, say, the crossword was specifically themed around whimsical collective nouns and there was a preamble stating as much

Comment: The original occurence of *"a postponement of trains"* seems to be from [1968](http://books.google.com/books?id=-pFZAAAAYAAJ&q=%22a+postponement+of+trains%22&dq=%22a+postponement+of+trains%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HSRVU7m4Du7S2wXpu4GQAg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ) in a book of collective nouns. The crossword author(s) did not seem to recognize that this phrase is uncommon, and was originally probably a joke.